# How do I output the name alongside the second smallest number only using while loops

Tags: python-3.x, string, while-loop, output

I have been trying to fix my code and have not been able to do so. My assignment asks me to output the second smallest score along with the student's name. I got the score part right but not the name part. Can you please help me?

```
n = int(input("Enter number of student: "))
    
minscore = 1000


i = 1

name = 0

while i <= n:

    print ("Please enter the name of student: ",i)
    x = str(input())
    print ("Please enter the score of student: ",i)
    y = int(input())

    if y < minscore:
            minscore2 = minscore
            minscore = y
            name = x
    elif y < minscore2:
        minscore2 = y
      
    i += 1

print ("Second lowest score is",x,"with score",minscore2)
```

Comment: When you find the 2nd lowest score also save the student name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you need to save the lowest name with the score.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of student: "))
    
minscore = 1000


i = 1

name = ''
name2 = 0


while i <= n:

    print ("Please enter the name of student: ",i)
    x = str(input())
    print ("Please enter the score of student: ",i)
    y = int(input())

    if y < minscore:
        minscore2 = minscore
        minscore = y
        name2 = name
        name = x
    elif y < minscore2:
        minscore2 = y
        name2 = x
      
    i += 1

print ("Second lowest score is",name2,"with score",minscore2)
```

A better way to go about this is to use lists and the .sort() method

```
n = int(input("Enter number of students: "))

names_with_scores = []

i = 1
while i <= n:
    names_with_scores.append([input("Please enter the name of student number " + str(i) + " : "), input("Please enter the score of student number " + str(i) + " : ")]) 
    # ^^^ Add name and scores to list inside a list ^^^ #

    i += 1

def sort_func(e):
    return e[1]

names_with_scores.sort(key=sort_func)
# Sorts the list in order of score #


print ("Second lowest score is " + str(names_with_scores[1][0]) + " with a score of " + names_with_scores[1][1])
```